# Is there a way to pass options values during mod_wsgi server start up in Django app

Tags: python-3.x, django, mod-wsgi

I am using **mod_wsgi** to run my Django app. As there are a plethora of options to define when the server run command is fired, I was trying to create some kind of python script to pass the options and their pre-set values.

For example:

Instead of using:

```
$python3 manage.py runmodwsgi --processes 3 --threads 1
```

I am trying to use a python script and use it as:

```
$python3 runme.py
```

where **runme.py** is the script file I am trying to use to start the server.

**What I have done so far?**

Created the script file:

```
import os
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', '<proj>.settings')
myargs = 'runmodwsgi'
list_of_args = ['', myargs]
execute_from_command_line(list_of_args)
```

As expected the server started with preset options, for example:

[image]

Now what I am trying to achieve is the pass values of certain options like:

```
--processes 3 --threads 1
```

and so on.

Is there a way I may pass the preset values (as I may be able to define in my script file **runme.py**), say something like adding to the list of arguments:

```
list_of_args = ['', myargs, addl_args]
```

I have been checking SO queries posted in addition to help available on python site, but could not get my head around to the problem.

I tried the following which is not very helpful though:

```
import os
import argparse # New import
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

# Addition of new code lines
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument("-p", "--processes", action="store_true")
group.add_argument("-t", "--threads", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("pint", type=int, help="no. of processes")
parser.add_argument("tint", type=int, help="no. of threads")

args = parser.parse_args()
# End of new code

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', '<proj>.settings')
myargs = 'runmodwsgi'

# At this line if I add ", args" (like shown below:])
list_of_args = ['', myargs, args] 
execute_from_command_line(list_of_args)
```

and run the command, it comes up with error:

```
TypeError: 'Namespace' object does not support indexing
```

If I simply run: `python3 runme.py`, I get the following error:

```
usage: runme.py [-h] [-p | -t] pint tint
runme.py: error: the following arguments are required: pint, tint
```

Whereas, using

```
python3 runme.py 3 1
```

starts the server but the options integers "3" and "1" does not have any effect (as intended for no. of processes and threads).

If I use:

```
python3 runme.py --processes 3 --threads 1
```

I get the following error:

```
usage: runme.py [-h] [-p | -t] pint tint
runme.py: error: argument -t/--threads: not allowed with argument -p/--processes
```

Tried with a single arg like:

```
python3 runme.py --processes 3 1
```

The server starts at this time but the options value/s are not affected.

**How do I define the option values and pass these preset values of options to the run command?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're just misunderstanding/misusing argparse.

```
import os
import sys
import argparse

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', '<proj>.settings')
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-p", "--processes", type=int, default=1)
parser.add_argument("-t", "--threads", type=int, default=1)
args = parser.parse_args()
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

command = [sys.argv[0], 'runmodwsgi', '--processes', str(args.processes), '--threads', str(args.threads)]
execute_from_command_line(command)
```

might be closer to what you want; it will default processes and threads both to 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have modified my script. However on trying to run, I am coming up with error `-bash: pyhton3: command not found`. Is it pointing me to the variable _command_ in the script? Or something else?

Comment: That... means you've typoed `pyhton3` likely in your shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/env pyhton3`) or on your bash command line: `$ pyhton3 runme.py`

Comment: I am sorry, there was a (**major**) typo. Now the terminal output says `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: With that exact code? On what line?

Comment: Yes, I am using the code suggested by you (with actual name of Django Project substituted). The error says (last but 1 line) 2089 of `File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/argparse.py` with `if not arg_string[0] in self.prefix_chars:`

Comment: Ah, right, sorry. Fixed in the post – `execute_from_command_line` requires all parameters to be strings.

Comment: Now I am getting error `Unknown command: '--processes'`.

Comment: Okay – one more fix: the first item in `command` needs to be the executable, not the command, so I added that too.

Comment: **It's a Beautiful Day!!** It works. **Thanks so very much.**